# Kann man auf etwas stolz sein, woran man nicht beteiligt ist/war?

Tags: meaning

Man kann selbstverständlich auf die Früchte eigener Arbeit stolz sein:

> Auf meine neueste Skulptur bin ich besonders stolz.

Man kann ganz allgemein einen stolzen Charakter haben (z. B. weil man toll aussieht und Arbeit in sein Aussehen gesteckt hat):

> Da kommt Albert, der stolze Gockel!

Man kann auf Personen stolz sein:

> Ich bin stolz auf Dich, meine Tochter!

Hier hat man natürlich Anteil am Werdegang der Tochter. Kann man auch auf einen Freund stolz sein, zu dessen Erfolg man nicht beigetragen hat? Ist man dann stolz auf sein Werk, oder ist man stolz, einen so erfolgreichen Freund gewonnen zu haben? Ich vermute, letzteres. Es ist also wieder gewissermaßen eine eigene Leistung.

Kann man stolz auf sein Land sein?

> *Wir* haben die Frauen-Fußball-WM gewonnen! Ich bin stolz auf die Mädels!

Wo ist da die eigene Leistung? Natürlich kann man sich freuen, natürlich kann man der eigenen Mannschaft Respekt bekunden. Aber woher kommt das Recht, stolz darauf sein zu können?

Und schließlich der Klassiker: Kann man stolz auf seine Nationalität sein?

> Ich bin stolz, Deutscher zu sein!

Es ist klar, dass man froh sein kann. Ich betrachte es auch als schier unfassbares Glück, in einer der schönsten Städte der Welt in einem der sichersten, wohlhabendsten und angenehmsten Länder der Welt zu wohnen.

Aber ich kann doch nichts dafür! Wie kann ich stolz darauf sein? Die Trümmerfrauen dürfen stolz sein, Deutschland nach dem Krieg wieder mitaufgebaut zu haben.

Oder verstehe ich das falsch, und der Fakt, dass ich in Deutschland geboren wurde, gibt mir einen *Grund*, stolz zu sein (wie Albert weiter oben wegen seines guten Aussehens)? Und wieso? Was kann ich denn dafür?

Gibt es also zwei verschiedene Arten von Stolz? Einmal das Gefühl, etwas erreicht zu haben, und einmal einfach eine Art Überheblichkeitsgefühl, einfach aus sich selbst heraus?

Comment: Die kurze Antwort: ja!

Comment: Deine Frage passt nicht zu deinen Beispielen. Wenn du Deutscher bist und darauf stolz bist, bist du, wenn auch nur indirekt, daran beteiligt. Das gleiche gilt für die Frauen-Fußball-WM. Du gehörst zu denen, deren "Mädels" die Frauen-Fußball-WM gewonnen haben. Du solltest daher die Frage konkretisieren. Vermutlich meinst du, ob man auf etwas stolz sein kann, was nicht der unmittelbar eigene Verdienst ist. Allerdings ist das keine Frage, die den Sprachgebrauch betrifft. Und somit gehört sie hier eigentlich nicht hin.

Comment: ganz einfach ist diese fragestellung nicht. eine begründung könnte sein, dass man stolz auf sein land oder auf die nationalmannschaft seines landes sein kann, weil man selbst ein teil dieser nation ist, und deshalb auch einen klitzekleinen anteil daran hat, wie es dem land und der gesellschaft geht, was indirekt auch einen einfluss auf die sportlichen erfolge haben kann

Comment: Die Frage ist zwar interessant, hat aber nicht speziell mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gerade etwas unter *stolz (adj.)* im Grimm nachgeschaut, es sind zig Seiten mit hunderten von Bedeutungen. Aufgefallen sind mir einige Beispiele unter 9 c β (*stolz auf eines (dabei doch deutlich die vorstellung von einem, der mit einem gefühl von stolz auf einen gegenstand blickt, von ihm für seinen stolz nahrung zieht*):

> ich (bin) stolz auf meinen urgroszvater *L. Schücking an A. v. Droste-Hülshoff* 24
>
> stolz auf das vaterland *A. v. Humboldt kosmos* 1, 40

Seit jeher wurde das Adjektiv *stolz* also in dieser Bedeutung verwendet.

Grundsätzlich kann man also auch stolz auf sein Vaterland sein. Dass diese Bedeutung in Deutschland ungern verwendet wird, ist ja eine andere Sache und auch eher eine der jüngeren Geschichte.

Um deine konkrete Frage zu beantworten: Es gibt nicht nur zwei Arten, stolz zu sein, sondern [hunderte](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=19,231,7). Beispiele dafür sind:

- der stolze mann (vgl. Habacuc 2, 5) im vollgefühl seiner männlichkeit, im bewusztsein seiner kraft; doch dann auch prächtig und stattlich durch kleidung und rüstung, wuchs und ansehen
- auch von vertretern einer nation, besonders ein stolzer Römer (Anton Ulrich von Braunschweig Octavia 1, 726); stolzer Spanier! Schiller 4, 27; vom bürgerthum
- noch deutlicher kehrt jugendliche kraftfülle, freude am geputzten kleid und mannichfachem aufwand hervor (besonders in der sphäre des liebeshandels) ein stolzer knabe
- besondere erwähnung finde der stolze bettler, welcher im kampfe mit seinem selbstbewusztsein, vor fremden thüren gaben heischen musz
- allgemein ein stolzer mensch huomo superbo Kramer dict. 2 (1702), 983a (auch: hieraus merkete Axel schon, mit was stolzen leuten ers zu tuhn haben würde Bucholtz Herkuliskus 19)
- eine neue sphäre erobert sich unser wort in verwendungen wie der stolze gelehrte
- mit der nebenbedeutung von 'spröde, zurückhaltend' die stolze jungfrau
- unter den wilden thieren der stolze löwe
- von einzelheiten des körperlichen eindrucks von mensch und thier (häufig im hinabsinken zum bloszen poetischen füllsel).
- noch deutlicher als seelische gesammtanlage (und so stärker zu b sich stellend) stoltz gemüt, undultig, unhandsam

Ich habe nur von einem Bruchteil der Bedeutungs- und Herkunftserklärungen den jeweiligen einleitenden Satz kopiert. Zusammenfassend vom Überfliegen kann man auf vieles stolz sein, darunter auch viele Dinge, für die man selbst nichts kann. Unzählige der Bedeutungen und Formulierungen werden heute nur noch selten oder gar nicht mehr verwendet.

Answer (score 9):

Ja, man kann auf seine Herkunft, seine Freunde und seine Fußballmannschaft stolz sein. Das ist der übliche Sprachgebrauch und entspricht auch dem, was die meisten Leute empfinden.

Ob die Leute das empfinden *sollen* und wenn ja, ob sie es sagen *sollen*, halte ich für off-topic.

Für die erfolgreiche Kommunikation ist es vielleicht noch von Interesse, dass ein signifikanter Anteil der Deutschen die Ansichten von fzwo teilt und von zur Schau gestelltem Stolz ohne gröbere Eigenleistung unangenehm berührt sind.

Answer (score 7):

#### Stolz ist die Freude, dazuzugehören.

(aber auch: Stolz ist das Gift des Geistes).

Da Stolz ein Gefühl ist besteht überhaupt kein Grund sich gegenüber irgendwem für das Gefühl zu rechtfertigen - Gefühle sind phänomenal, sie sind da und fertig.

Man kann sie nicht ausreden, sondern allenfalls leugnen/verstecken/sich ihrer schämen - wobei die Scham auch so ein Gefühl ist, dem ständig nachgesagt wird, falsch zu sein.

Freude zum Großvater, zur Brücke, an der man mitgebaut hat, zur Nationalmannschaft dazuzugehören als Angehöriger, Architekt oder Bauarbeiter, und Fan ist da oder ist nicht da.

In Deutschland ist die Kritik an Stolz ohne Leistung aber verbreitet, und richtige Deutsche schämen sich dafür, Deutsch zu sein. :)

Im Ernst - bei Gruppenidentitäten ist Stolz das normalste der Welt, und unproblematisch. Problematisch sind oft die Konsequenzen, die aus dem Gefühl gezogen werden. Nicht selten sind die Konsequenzen gruselig.

Answer (score 3):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stolz) geht das schon:

> von Selbstbewusstsein und Freude über einen Besitz, eine [eigene] Leistung erfüllt; ein entsprechendes Gefühl zum Ausdruck bringend oder hervorrufend

*eigene* ist eingeklammert, demnach optional. Man kann also sehr Wohl auf die Leistung anderer stolz sein (z. B. die einer Fußballmannschaft).

Wenn es um

> Ich bin stolz, Deutscher zu sein!

geht, muss man wohl etwas kreativer werden. Vielleicht ist man stolz auf die Menschen, die aus Deutschland das gemacht haben, was es jetzt ist (Gründer, Politiker, deutsche Unternehmer, Erfinder, Wirtschafter (oder heißt es Wirte?), etc.).